# How to add existing directory to PHPStorm project based on existing files on remote host?

Tags: directory, project, addition, phpstorm

I've created PHPStorm project based on existing files (Web server is on remote host, files are accessible via mounted drive). I've included some folders and excluded some ones.

How to add existing folder which was excluded on creation to project now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Directories` to see any excluded **local** folders.

`Settings | Deployment | Excluded Paths` to see list of excluded folders from Deployment actions.

After that just use **Remote Host tool window** (or `Tools | Deployment | Browse Remote Host`) to browse and download any missing folders manually.

Comment: How can I make PHPStorm download the previously excluded files and folders to my local project, without having to sync or re-download the whole project?

Comment: @J.Meijer Use `Remote Host` tool window to browse remote site and download from there.